# AngularJS if ng-repeat item is out of parent div - set class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If the item partially or fully not visible in parent div, i need to set class "novisible" for invisible items (when user scrolling dynamic). How to detect, that items beyond of border parent div?

```css
.item {
height:30px;
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: auto;">
  
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the heights always be `30/300px`?

Comment: can you be specific what you want

Comment: Yes, the item height always 30px, but parent div - relative height (depends of window size).